# WiFi router flash layout - brick?

Tags: firmware

I'm working on to get openwrt to this Linksys e3200 router.
Stock and wrt firmware did flash ok through web interface.

In the progress of testing different openwrt builds I happen to brick it.

I have bios programmer and flashrom connected. The firmware files is a about 7mb and 11mb in size, the chip is 16mb.
I did truncate the files and flashed ok.

I do only get dim lights on ports. No TTL/serial.

Do you think the flash layout is the cause of something else?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE! Could you rephrase the last bit so we know what it is you want to know? As it stands you are inviting guesses and opinions, but not answers.

Comment: I solved this myself googling!

Comment: you could garner some upvotes by telling how beyond stating _that_ you found something and beyond a mere link (which could go stale).